Getting Validation Errors in Marshmallow schema
I am using the Marshmallow library for data validation and serialization. I am allowing None values for some fields in my schema, but I keep getting validation errors even though I have set allow_none = True.
class MySchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True, allow_none=True)
    age = fields.Integer(allow_none=True)

schema = MySchema()

data = {"age": None}
result = schema.load(data)
print(result)


Why is it failing validation for the 'name' field even though allow_none = True ?

Your code runs for me without producing any validation errors. I'm using Python 3.12 (and Marshmallow 3.22.0).

you are right, I actually already have the fix in my code which is to pass "name": None but messed up the testing. edited it to take it back to a point where it failed

Why have you set the name and age fields differently? Your age field is defined properly, so just copy the same to name field.
You set required=True which means you can't leave out the name field.
Remove required=True from the name field.

ah yeah that makes sense. I actually did this intentionally because I wanted the user to set some name always even if it is none. your fix works. another fix is to just pass "name": None in the data object.
